# Remove initials in Author names in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to remove only initials from the list of names:

Input:

```
Bland-Hawthorn, J., van S\"{u}tterlin Breugel, W., Gillingham, P.R., \& Baldray, I.K.
Bettonvil, F.C.M., Hammerschlag, R.H., S\"{u}tterlin, P., et al.
Puschmann, K.G., Kneer, F., Seelemann, T., \& Wittmann, A.D.
Ramsay, J.V., Norton, D.G., \& Mugridge, E.G.V.  
Rutten, R.J.  2007
```

Output:

```
Bland-Hawthorn, van S\"{u}tterlin Breugel, Gillingham, \& Baldray,
Bettonvil, Hammerschlag, S\"{u}tterlin, et al.
Puschmann, Kneer, Seelemann, \& Wittmann
Ramsay, Norton, \& Mugridge
Rutten
```

My Regex:

```
$str=~s/[^A-Z]([A-Z])\.?\s+/ /g for(0..5);
$str=~s/\s([A-Z])\.([A-Z])\.?\,?/ /g;
$str=~s/\,\s*([A-Z])\.\,/,/g;
```

I thought there a different way to achieve the output. Anyhow my regex is a very low rank to get the output.

Anyone could help me to find a module or else something in different regex patterns on complexity names if we found like `de van der`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your code works for the example you show, and you want help changing it so it works for an example you do not show. Please [edit] and show the input that breaks your code.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

The following script seems to work with your sample data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @surnames;

while (my $authors = <DATA>) {
    $authors =~ /\S/ or last;
    $authors =~ s/\s+\z//;
    my @authors = split qr{\.,\s+(?:\Q\&\E\s+)?}, $authors;
    push @surnames, author_list_to_string( [ map /^([^,]+)/, @authors ] );
}

print "'$_'\n" for @surnames;

sub author_list_to_string {
    my $author_list = shift;

    if ( $author_list->[-1] eq 'et al.' ) {
        return join(', ', @$author_list);
    }

    if (@$author_list == 1) {
        return $author_list->[0];
    }

    if (@$author_list == 2) {
        return join(', \& ', @$author_list);
    }

    return join(', \& ',
        join(', ', @{$author_list}[0 .. ($#$author_list - 1)]),
        $author_list->[-1]
    );
}

__DATA__
Bland-Hawthorn, J., van S\"{u}tterlin Breugel, W., Gillingham, P.R., \& Baldray, I.K.
Bettonvil, F.C.M., Hammerschlag, R.H., S\"{u}tterlin, P., et al.
Puschmann, K.G., Kneer, F., Seelemann, T., \& Wittmann, A.D.
Ramsay, J.V., Norton, D.G., \& Mugridge, E.G.V.
Rutten, R.J.  2007
```

If your needs are more complicated, you may be able to benefit from using [Lingua::EN::NameParse](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::NameParse).

Answer (score 1):

The following *regex* should do it ...

```
(?:[A-Z]\.){1,3},?
```

see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Bxa6Ma/3)**

**perl** ( [demo](http://rextester.com/KDQ52538) )

```
$str = 'Bland-Hawthorn, J., van S\\"{u}tterlin Breugel, W., Gillingham, P.R., \\& Baldray, I.K.
Bettonvil, F.C.M., Hammerschlag, R.H., S\\"{u}tterlin, P., et al.
Puschmann, K.G., Kneer, F., Seelemann, T., \\& Wittmann, A.D.
Ramsay, J.V., Norton, D.G., \\& Mugridge, E.G.V.  
Rutten, R.J.  2007 ';
$regex = qr/(?:[A-Z]\.){1,3},?/p;
$subst = '';
$result = $str =~ s/$regex/$subst/rg;
print "$result";
```